# Leaflet, panTo map location when link is clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, leaflet

Does anyone know leaflet? Im trying to make a function where you click on a link and the map goes to a location. Im trying with putting a pointfield value under the "value"-attribute like this:

```
<a href="#" class="marker" value="{{ mymodel.pt }}">Link</a>
```

And then i want to do something like this but it's not working:

```
$("#dialog").on("click", ".marker", function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      map.panTo([$(this).attr("value")]);  
});
```

Any ideas or alternative solutions? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Leaflet expects a LatLng object or at least a two-element array as the first parameter for the panTo-function (see: http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#latlng)

I'm not sure what 'mymodel.pt' contains, but make sure that you end up with something like this for the actual value:

```
<a href="#" class="marker" value="[50,50]">Link</a>
```

And change the JS slightly:

```
...
  map.panTo($(this).attr("value"));  
...
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The mymodel.pt cointains a Django pointfield which should contain the coordinates in that format. But i've also tried just writing simple test values in the way you describe but i seems to do nothing. Im a beginner with js/jquery but im wondering if im callin 'map' the wrong way..

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! 
Just making sure: 'map' points to a leaflet map object, right? Does the callback-method work (maybe drop a console.log there)?

Comment: Yes. The map is under a document ready function and looks like this: var map = L.map('map').setView([xx.xxxx, xx.xxxx], 15); like they describe it on the leaflet homepage. That part works fine. But this script is not under the same document ready function could that be the problem? That it doesnt find the variable 'map'?

Comment: That's the most likely explanation, different scopes. Try adding the jQuery call somewhere after your map initialization. Also: console.log(map) in the callback function tells you what the browser thinks the 'map' variable contains.

Comment: Alright! Is it possible to get the var map (in that different scope) without moving the function somehow? I'll have to look into the console.log thing. I have not worked with that before. Thanks again for helping med out.

Comment: No problem! Be sure to know your console, it's crazy useful. Here's a tutorial: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/developertools/part1/?redirect_from_locale=de

Comment: As for the scope: You could tie your 'map' variable to something in the global scope, window for example: window.map = L.map ... and then reference it accordingly in your jQuery-callback: window.map.panTo ...

Comment: OK i'll try that. I was thinking of maybe writing a panTo function and put it under the map script and call it from the click-event. Do you think that could work?

Comment: That would definitely make for better code. Make sure that the jQuery-call of that function is below it, however. Otherwise you'll run into the scope-issue again.

Comment: OK. Cool. Back to the lab. I'll may have to come back with some follow ups questions! :)

Comment: Not sure how to pass the "value" from the click when calling this function. Would you mind just giving me a small example on how to set this up? And does the jquery call also have to be inside the map-script or just after it?

Comment: Could you set that up as a new question (the comment thread is getting quite packed ;)). Possibly with some jsfiddle of what you have so far, that would be helpful.

Comment: Yeah you're right about that! I created this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21710530/leaflet-panto-or-setview-function