# Leaflet panTo (or setview) function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, dictionary, leaflet

I want to create a panTo -function. When I click a link the map pans to the coordinates. But im not sure how to pass the value to the function. I'm starting with giving the link the Pointfield (pt) value like this:

```
<a href="#" class="marker" value="{{ mymodel.pt }}">Link</a>
```

Then I've been trying this:

```
$("#dialog").on("click", ".marker", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    map.panTo($(this).attr("value"));
    });
```

That didn't work. I think it's a scope-issue where the function cant read the 'map' variable because it's not under the initial map script.

So my next idea is to create a "panTo"- function and place it under the inital map script (which would be the right scope) and call that function from the click event instead. Not sure it would work but Im wondering how to pass it the "value" from the link?

Thanks for your answers!

Comment: Asking for clarification: do you want your map to have an animated pan to the location or to simply view a location based on a button? The former hasn't been a supported feature since the early versions of leaflet, but the latter is definitely doable.

Comment: hey thanks for your answer! It's not so important which one. What i want is to be able to list some objects from my database in a dialog box with the map in the background. Each object has a link and when you click it the map goes to the coordinates. Something like that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can add navigation to your map by utilizing `data` attributes in your HTML. Save the latitude,longitude and zoom to something like `data-position` and then call those values with some JavaScript when the user clicks on the anchor tag. Here's some code to illustrate.

```
<div id="map">
    <div id="map-navigation" class="map-navigation">
        <a href="#" data-zoom="12" data-position="37.7733,-122.4367">
            San Francisco
        </a>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
var map = L.map('map').setView([51.505, -0.09], 13);

L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.cloudmade.com/BC9A493B41014CAABB98F0471D759707/997/256/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
                maxZoom: 18,
                attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, <a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, Imagery © <a href="http://cloudmade.com">CloudMade</a>'
            }).addTo(map);

document.getElementById('map-navigation').onclick = function(e) {
    var pos = e.target.getAttribute('data-position');
    var zoom = e.target.getAttribute('data-zoom');
    if (pos && zoom) {
        var loc = pos.split(',');
        var z = parseInt(zoom);
        map.setView(loc, z, {animation: true});
        return false;
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Awesome! Great answer. I'll play around with this and see if i can make it work! Thanks man

Comment: I'm trying to put the script under my "$(document).ready(function () {" where i also declare my map, tile layer and where have some other functions connected to the map. I'm wondering if i have to wrap it somehow? Or if i need to declare the dialog also? Because i've put the anchor link in a child-html which i load into a jquery dialog on the main page.