# getElementById in jquery dialog?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I is it any way i can make this work:

```
document.getElementById('someid').onclick = function(e) {
```

If the element is in a child html loaded into a jquery-dialog?

Edit:

Just to be clear. Im trying this map-view function which i didn't write myself. It looks like this:

```
document.getElementById('map-navigation').onclick = function(e) {
var pos = e.target.getAttribute('data-position');
var zoom = e.target.getAttribute('data-zoom');
  if (pos && zoom) {
    var loc = pos.split(',');
    var z = parseInt(zoom);
    map.setView(loc, z, {animation: true});
    return false;
  }
}
```

It works when i put the anchor on the main page but not if i put it in the child-html which i load into a dialog (#dialog)

Comment: Are you using jQuery? I ask because you have the jQuery tag, but your code doesn't seem to be using it.

Comment: any example of what jQuery dialog you mean?code snippet or fiddle?

Comment: It's a jquery UI dialog box. Yes im also using jquery.

Comment: Like this..? http://jsfiddle.net/kh2Af/

Comment: Yes somthing like that. But the content in the dialog is a loaded child-template-html which contains a div with the #someid. When i click it i want the function to start.

Comment: Question is when `#map-navigation` enters the DOM, if you're dialog is e.g. an AJAX request and inserts the HTML dynamically you likely assign a click handler to an object which isn't existing at this moment of time. For this try the second method in Zero21xxx's answer, essentially using event delegation.

Comment: Ah right. This might be the problem. I actually open the dialog and use the load($(this).attr("href") method to get the content into the dialog. But i cant place this function under there beacuse of problems with a map-variable and the scopes. So i need to put it with the other map scripts which comes before..

Comment: this was my orginal post just to clearify: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21710530/leaflet-panto-or-setview-function/21761152#21761152

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('someid').on('click', function(e) {...}
```

Something like that will work. `on` let's you attach events to elements that exist now or will exist in the future.

If that element isn't on the page on load, you could do something like

```
$('body').on('click','someid', function(e) {...}
```

**UPDATE**
To incorporate the code you added, you could write the handler like this:

```
$('body').on('click','someid', function(e) {
  var pos = e.target.getAttribute('data-position');
  , zoom = e.target.getAttribute('data-zoom')
  , loc
  , z;
  if (pos && zoom) {
      loc = pos.split(',');
      z = parseInt(zoom, 10);
      map.setView(loc, z, {animation: true});
      return false;
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Yes i know. But I'm just trying a function which i haven't written myself. I'm a beginner with this and i can't make the rest work with jquery yet so i was just wondering if there was an easy way to make it work with the one i got..

Comment: You can also use `$('someid').on('click', someFunction)` to call some already defined function. Notice the missing `()` when referring to `someFunction`, it's an important difference as `someFunction()` would evaluate `someFunction` and use it's return value as a click callback - you rarely want to do this!

Comment: @Zero21xxx , How can i modify the rest of the function to work with the second alternative. Because it wont work with getAttribute or would it? If you look at my edit.

Comment: @user3199840 I updated my answer. Anything beyond this and I would suggest doing some personal discovery to figure the rest out.

Answer (score 0):

If you are only using click function then you can go for .click() API

```
$('#yourId').click(function()
{
   //Function callback logic
})
```

Besides this you can also go for .on() (version 1.7+) and .bind() to attach events. Checkout their documentation on http://api.jquery.com/on/ and https://api.jquery.com/bind/

Comment: Thank you. I've tried that but it doesn't go with the rest of the function and i'm not skilled enough to rewrite it with jquery just yet.

Answer (score 0):

Simply like this:

```
document.getElementById('idOfYourDialog').getElementId('elementInDialog').onclick = function()
{
    //Some Code
}
```

Or, if you want to do it in JQuery,

```
$('#idOfYourDialog #elementInDialog').on('click', function()
{
    //Some Code
});
```

[<kbd>Demo</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/kh2Af/1/)

Comment: Yes i think that might be what i was thinking of. I'll try that